# Javascript div onhover increment count

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a few div's. each div has a unique id.

Here are the div's:

```
<div id="1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
<div id="3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
<div id="4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
<div id="5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
<div id="6"><p>Box 6</p></div>
<div id="7"><p>Box 7</p></div>
<div id="8"><p>Box 8</p></div>
<div id="9"><p>Box 9</p></div>
```

And here is a sample of how the data would look.

```
<script>

counter = [

  {id: 1, hovers: 0},
  {id: 2, hovers: 0},
  {id: 3, hovers: 0},
  {id: 4, hovers: 0},
  {id: 5, hovers: 0},
  {id: 6, hovers: 0},
  {id: 7, hovers: 0},
  {id: 8, hovers: 0},
  {id: 9, hovers: 0}

]

</script>
```

What I need to do is that each time a specific div is hovered it's hovers value increments by 1.

How can I do this with Javascript?

Comment: Have you done your research? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `find()` method to find specific object with that id and if object is found increment its hovers property.

```js
var counter = [{id: 1, hovers: 0},{id: 2, hovers: 0},{id: 3, hovers: 0},{id: 4, hovers: 0},{id: 5, hovers: 0},{id: 6, hovers: 0},{id: 7, hovers: 0},{id: 8, hovers: 0},{id: 9, hovers: 0}]

$('div').mouseover(function() {
  var obj = counter.find(e => e.id == $(this).attr('id'))
  if(obj) obj.hovers++
  console.log(obj)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
<div id="3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
<div id="4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
<div id="5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
<div id="6"><p>Box 6</p></div>
<div id="7"><p>Box 7</p></div>
<div id="8"><p>Box 8</p></div>
<div id="9"><p>Box 9</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a hover listener and store the hover amount in an attribute, then you don't need to declare the total number of div's as a variable beforehand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div").hover(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("cnt") == null) {
            $(this).attr("cnt", "0");
        }
        $(this).attr("cnt", parseInt($(this).attr("cnt")) + 1);
    });
</script>
```

HTML will become `<div id="4" cnt="12">`

Answer (score 0):

## Without jQuery

---

You need to listen for the [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) event:

```js
var counters = [
    {id: 1, hovers: 0},
    {id: 2, hovers: 0},
    {id: 3, hovers: 0},
    {id: 4, hovers: 0},
    {id: 5, hovers: 0},
    {id: 6, hovers: 0},
    {id: 7, hovers: 0},
    {id: 8, hovers: 0},
    {id: 9, hovers: 0}
];

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var divs = container.children;
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
   var div = divs.item(i);
   div.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (evt) {
       var id = evt.target.id;
       var counter = findElement(counters, id);
       if (counter) {
           counter.hovers++;
           console.log(counter);
       }
   });
}

function findElement(array, id) {
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i].id == id)
          return array[i];
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
    <div id="2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
    <div id="3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
    <div id="4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
    <div id="5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
    <div id="6"><p>Box 6</p></div>
    <div id="7"><p>Box 7</p></div>
    <div id="8"><p>Box 8</p></div>
    <div id="9"><p>Box 9</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The important thing is to use the mouseenter event.** You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover). Don't confuse it with mouseover, which is technically incorrect for your example because it will also trigger on child elements (in your case `<p>`) which would cause your hover count to be off.

Here is how you can solve your problem using JavaScript:

```js
(function(){

  var counter = [
    {id: 1, hovers: 0},
    {id: 2, hovers: 0},
    {id: 3, hovers: 0},
    {id: 4, hovers: 0},
    {id: 5, hovers: 0},
    {id: 6, hovers: 0},
    {id: 7, hovers: 0},
    {id: 8, hovers: 0},
    {id: 9, hovers: 0}
  ];

  // Use a named function, not an anonymous function
  // The event {Object} parameter is passed from mouseenter
  function updateHoverCount(event){

      // Array.forEach is used here because if the order
      // of counter wasn't perfectly defined
      // (EG: id of 3, id of 1, ... id of [0-9])
      // this will find the right object first and
      // then update the hover count
      counter.forEach(function(ele, i){

          // Match the id against the event target
          if(ele.id === Number(event.target.id)){
              ele.hovers += 1;

              // Logging to show in example
              console.log('Element'
                          , event.target
                          , 'Total Hovers:'
                          , ele.hovers);
          }

      });
  }

  // Iterate over your counter to find the elements
  counter.forEach(function(ele, i){

      // Variable storage isn't necessary, it's provided for clarity
      var div = document.getElementById(String(ele.id));

      // Add the mouseenter (not mouseover) event to the div
      div.addEventListener('mouseenter', updateHoverCount);

  });
    
})();
```

```html
<div id="1"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Box 2</p></div>
<div id="3"><p>Box 3</p></div>
<div id="4"><p>Box 4</p></div>
<div id="5"><p>Box 5</p></div>
<div id="6"><p>Box 6</p></div>
<div id="7"><p>Box 7</p></div>
<div id="8"><p>Box 8</p></div>
<div id="9"><p>Box 9</p></div>
```

---

Pay attention to the use of `.forEach` on the Array prototype. You may have to shim your website or application depending on browser requirements. You can review browser specifications [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example#Browser_compatibility). Shims are required for < IE9 and older mobile browsers.